# mv command not working - Error: no package mv available

Tags: linux, package, mv

run the mv command but nothing happened so I tried to install it:

```
# yum install mv
```

then i got the Nothing to do response with error : no package mv available

Any pointers on how to set up the mv command in Apache 2.2.15 on Centos 6.

Thank you very much in advance

N.B The last 3 lines after issuing the yum install mv:

Setting up Install Process
No package mv available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: You mean 'coreutils' yeah ? :)

Comment: @FreudianSlip Yes, thanks. Error corrected (and converted to an answer) :)

Answer (score 2):

Please explain *nothing happened*.

`mv` belongs to the `coreutils`. If you don't have `mv` installed then your system is seriously broken. But I'm very sure you have `mv` installed, otherwise you would see an error message like `mv: command not found`.

If there is no error, then `mv` won't print any output at all. This is the intended behavior. If you want to force output, then append the argument `-v` for *verbose* mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `type` command to see if your mv has been incorrectly aliased to something else.
Mine is:

```
$ type mv
  mv is /bin/mv
```

Yours may be something like

```
$ type mv
  mv is an alias for
```

You can use the unalias command to correct this type of problem.

```
$ unalias mv
```

Comment: you are correct, type mv outputs "mv is aliased to `mv -i'. Unalaising worked. Thanks everyone for your input.